combine all sheets in to one sheet in which Column counts are different from all the sheets
I have multiple workbooks.
Book1 having Columns Date,Range,Ref1,Ref2,Ref3,Ref4...
Book2 having Columns Date,Range,Ref1,Ref3,Ref5,Ref7
Book3 having Columns Date,Longitude,Ref1,Ref2,Ref3,Ref4,Ref5,Ref6
I need to combine/append only particular columns from all the sheets through Power Query.
For ex.If I need only Date,Ref1,Ref3 from all the sheets how Can I do it?

Thank you.

Have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/choose-remove-columns and Append queries (Power Query) - Microsoft Support?

Are these in the same folder? Or are you referencing each file?

these are in same folder @Ethan

did you figure it out?

you need to make sure the column names in each sheet are the same. e.g. change the longitude to range
then you can try append queries in PQ



at last you can remove the column you don't want or choose the column that you want

Since you are referencing these in the same folder, you can get the file paths from the folder and then insert a function that repeats for each file in that folder.
Here is what your function can be...
I called this function fnStackOverflow:
(fileName as text) =>
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(fileName), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"Date", "Ref-1", "Ref-3"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"

Then you can create a table called StackOverflow and reference the function above like this:
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\StackOverflow\Desktop\2024\September\0925\Test"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Name", "Folder Path"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{"Folder Path", "Name"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"FilePath"),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Columns", "fnStackOverflow", each fnStackOverflow([FilePath])),
    #"Expanded fnStackOverflow" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "fnStackOverflow", {"Date", "Ref-1", "Ref-3"}, {"Date", "Ref-1", "Ref-3"})
in
    #"Expanded fnStackOverflow"

